# How can I hold two cylinders together and be able to release them?

Tags: adhesive

I have two cylindrical (metallic) objects, of different diameters but both above 0.5cm and under 2cm (actually it's a bit more complicated but let's leave it at that). Their lengths are at least 0.5m each.

I want to hold these two cylinders together against being pulled apart (away from each other perpendicular to the axis); it would also be nice if I could prevent them being pulled in opposite directions along their axis, but that's not very significant.

[image]

I could obviously tape them together, or glue them together; but - that's a semi-permanent solution, and taking them back apart and together again repeatedly is either messy, ineffective or impossible. No, I want something that can be undone or taken apart.

<sub>PS - Help me tag this question?</sub>

Comment: Are they ferrous?

Comment: @CaiusJard: They're metallic, but I don't think they're ferrous.

Comment: May you drill holes in the cylinders?

Comment: @CaiusJard: One of them - definitely not, the other one - not sure. But write your answer, because other people may have different constraints than mine.

Comment: What other constraints must be maintained? For example: Must the objects be in intimate contact along their length? Is the requirement for storage? Use? (Have you discovered if a magnet sticks to one yet?) Can you name any common object(s) which would have (or benefit from) this ability?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as being too vague to any practical application and too "click-bait" for any non-opinion based answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use velcro cable ties:

[image: Cable tie]

Rubber bands also work.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution assumes that you are allowed to keep the two cylinders slightly apart, as long as they're resistant to pulling.

---

There's this kind of part which you can get:

[image]

It's (sometimes) called a "U clamp".  And there's another interesting invention called a "sleeve nut" or "sex-bolt":

[image]

So, if you:

1. Get a U clamp with the diameter of the larger cylinder
2. Get a U clamp with the diameter of the smaller cylinder
3. Get a sleeve-nut which matches the dimensions of the hole in the U-clamps (perhaps adjusting the width of one of the U-clamp holes)
4. Fasten the two clams with the two sides of the nut and a screwdriver or Allen wrench
5. Repeat the above with at least one other pair of U-clamps (so that the cylinders aren't held together at just one point).

It should theoretically give you the kind of device you want. But TBH this is just an idea which *should* work, not something I've tried yet.

Comment: You're answering your own question and refer to the OP as 'you' which seems odd. This solution does not allow cylinders to be in intimate contact with each other along their full length without additional pieces. Is that a limitation? Must the pieces touch each other along their entire length as your drawing shows? What distance must the two cylinders (tubes?) be in relationship to each other?

Comment: @Stan: "seems odd" <- It's customary on other StackExchange sites. The fact that I'm the author is not consequential. Now, what you've said is true, and I'll edit that into the answer.

Comment: Lifehacks works a bit differently than other StackExchange sites. Peek at the [Tour] and [Help] to get a better idea of how this site differs from other SE sites. "It should theoretically give ***you*** the kind of device ***you*** want"—is the 'odd' part I referred to. I now ask you, what was the issue that your question was supposed to solve for you. If it's a hypothetical question, what is/are example(s) of this requirement in your everyday (or sometime) needs? What two (hypothetical) cylindrical objects would an individual want to have attached in the manner you describe?

Comment: Are you trying to create a comprehensive answer to a generalized question? Are you presenting an answer for a need that has not been specifically articulated? "If you are looking for a canonical means to temporarily attach two different cylindrical radiuses and whose length  does not exceeding 0.5m, what are the ways to do this?" Lacking more detail in the question, pushes this enquiry into an enigma with no best answer.

Comment: @Stan: Somewhere in-between these two extremes. Also, sometimes it's fine when a somewhat-general question has [several good answers but no one "right" answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/174984/avoiding-dust-scattering-when-you-drill).

Answer (score 0):

Place the two pieces together into a fitted bag or container made from suitable materials so that they remain in contact or in pockets which keep them a desirable, prescribed distance from each other.

You can separate the cylinders by removing one or both of them from the container—and by replacing them whenever you require them to be together—repeatedly without additional materials or waste to do so.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can temporarily clamp the two pieces together with the old…
**"Napkin Ring" Hack**: You (or anyone) can place the two cylindrical pieces inside a stiff ring "O" with an inside diameter equal to both their diameters, i.e. (2R<sub>1</sub>+2R<sub>2</sub>)
[image: Napkin Ring Hack]
Ring Diameter (I.D.) = (2R<sub>1</sub>+2R<sub>2</sub>)  or an inside radius of half that.

Need a more reliable hold? Use two rings—put one at either end of the pair of cylinders.

EDIT: Napkin rings, at their simplest, look like this…

[image: Napkin rings]

and are normally used like this to hold a table napkin rather than place it folded beside the dinner plate at a place setting.

[image: Napkin ring use]

Good luck.

Comment: Stiff ring made from a napkin?